# stripe SDK integration using swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am attempting to add the stripe SDK to my iOS swift project and have many instances with this error "the Use of undeclared type 'STPContactField'" as shown below:

I have already attempted:

1. clean and build
2. reinstall podfiles
3. make sure the search path is correct
4. project is open in newly generated workspace, not standard project

[image: first set of errors] [image: second set of errors]after downloading the stripe files from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios I am using the files speciffically from this link here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)

all of the code from the view controller with issues is here:

```
import UIKit
import Stripe
import Alamofire





struct Settings {
    let theme: STPTheme
    let additionalPaymentMethods: STPPaymentMethodType
    let requiredBillingAddressFields: STPBillingAddressFields
    let requiredShippingAddressFields: Set<STPContactField>
    let shippingType: STPShippingType
}

class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {
    var settings: Settings {
        return Settings(theme: self.theme.stpTheme,
                        additionalPaymentMethods: self.applePay.enabled ? .all : STPPaymentMethodType(),
                        requiredBillingAddressFields: self.requiredBillingAddressFields.stpBillingAddressFields,
                        requiredShippingAddressFields: self.requiredShippingAddressFields.stpContactFields,
                        shippingType: self.shippingType.stpShippingType)
    }

    private var theme: Theme = .Default
    private var applePay: Switch = .Enabled
    private var requiredBillingAddressFields: RequiredBillingAddressFields = .None
    private var requiredShippingAddressFields: RequiredShippingAddressFields = .PostalAddressPhone
    private var shippingType: ShippingType = .Shipping

    fileprivate enum Section: String {
        case Theme = "Theme"
        case ApplePay = "Apple Pay"
        case RequiredBillingAddressFields = "Required Billing Address Fields"
        case RequiredShippingAddressFields = "Required Shipping Address Fields"
        case ShippingType = "Shipping Type"
        case Session = "Session"

        init(section: Int) {
            switch section {
            case 0: self = .Theme
            case 1: self = .ApplePay
            case 2: self = .RequiredBillingAddressFields
            case 3: self = .RequiredShippingAddressFields
            case 4: self = .ShippingType
            default: self = .Session
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate enum Theme: String {
        case Default = "Default"
        case CustomLight = "Custom – Light"
        case CustomDark = "Custom – Dark"

        init(row: Int) {
            switch row {
            case 0: self = .Default
            case 1: self = .CustomLight
            default: self = .CustomDark
            }
        }

        var stpTheme: STPTheme {
            switch self {
            case .Default:
                return STPTheme.default()
            case .CustomLight:
                let theme = STPTheme()
                theme.primaryBackgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.96, blue:0.95, alpha:1.00)
                theme.secondaryBackgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.00)
                theme.primaryForegroundColor = UIColor(red:0.35, green:0.35, blue:0.35, alpha:1.00)
                theme.secondaryForegroundColor = UIColor(red:0.66, green:0.66, blue:0.66, alpha:1.00)
                theme.accentColor = UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.81, blue:0.51, alpha:1.00)
                theme.errorColor = UIColor(red:0.87, green:0.18, blue:0.20, alpha:1.00)
                theme.font = UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Light", size: 17)
                theme.emphasisFont = UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Bold", size: 17)
                return theme
            case .CustomDark:
                let theme = STPTheme()
                theme.primaryBackgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.23, blue:0.31, alpha:1.00)
                theme.secondaryBackgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.29, blue:0.38, alpha:1.00)
                theme.primaryForegroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.00)
                theme.secondaryForegroundColor = UIColor(red:0.60, green:0.64, blue:0.71, alpha:1.00)
                theme.accentColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.80, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00)
                theme.errorColor = UIColor(red:0.85, green:0.48, blue:0.48, alpha:1.00)
                theme.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans", size: 17)
                theme.emphasisFont = UIFont(name: "GillSans", size: 17)
                return theme
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate enum Switch: String {
        case Enabled = "Enabled"
        case Disabled = "Disabled"

        init(row: Int) {
            self = (row == 0) ? .Enabled : .Disabled
        }

        var enabled: Bool {
            return self == .Enabled
        }
    }

    fileprivate enum RequiredBillingAddressFields: String {
        case None = "None"
        case Zip = "Zip"
        case Full = "Full"

        init(row: Int) {
            switch row {
            case 0: self = .None
            case 1: self = .Zip
            default: self = .Full
            }
        }

        var stpBillingAddressFields: STPBillingAddressFields {
            switch self {
            case .None: return .none
            case .Zip: return .zip
            case .Full: return .full
            }
        }
    }

    private enum RequiredShippingAddressFields: String {
        case None = "None"
        case Email = "Email"
        case PostalAddressPhone = "(PostalAddress|Phone)"
        case All = "All"

        init(row: Int) {
            switch row {
            case 0: self = .None
            case 1: self = .Email
            case 2: self = .PostalAddressPhone
            default: self = .All
            }
        }

        var stpContactFields: Set<STPContactField> {
            switch self {
            case .None: return []
            case .Email: return [.emailAddress]
            case .PostalAddressPhone: return [.postalAddress, .phoneNumber]
            case .All: return [.postalAddress, .phoneNumber, .emailAddress, .name]
            }
        }

    }

    private enum ShippingType: String {
        case Shipping = "Shipping"
        case Delivery = "Delivery"

        init(row: Int) {
            switch row {
            case 0: self = .Shipping
            default: self = .Delivery
            }
        }

        var stpShippingType: STPShippingType {
            switch self {
            case .Shipping: return .shipping
            case .Delivery: return .delivery
            }
        }
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(style: .grouped)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "Settings"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismiss as () -> Void))
    }

    @objc func dismiss() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch Section(section: section) {
        case .Theme: return 3
        case .ApplePay: return 2
        case .RequiredBillingAddressFields: return 3
        case .RequiredShippingAddressFields: return 4
        case .ShippingType: return 2
        case .Session: return 1
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return Section(section: section).rawValue
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        switch Section(section: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section) {
        case .Theme:
            let value = Theme(row: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
            cell.textLabel?.text = value.rawValue
            cell.accessoryType = value == self.theme ? .checkmark : .none
        case .ApplePay:
            let value = Switch(row: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
            cell.textLabel?.text = value.rawValue
            cell.accessoryType = value == self.applePay ? .checkmark : .none
        case .RequiredBillingAddressFields:
            let value = RequiredBillingAddressFields(row: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
            cell.textLabel?.text = value.rawValue
            cell.accessoryType = value == self.requiredBillingAddressFields ? .checkmark : .none
        case .RequiredShippingAddressFields:
            let value = RequiredShippingAddressFields(row: indexPath.row)
            cell.textLabel?.text = value.rawValue
            cell.accessoryType = value == self.requiredShippingAddressFields ? .checkmark : .none
        case .ShippingType:
            let value = ShippingType(row: indexPath.row)
            cell.textLabel?.text = value.rawValue
            cell.accessoryType = value == self.shippingType ? .checkmark : .none
        case .Session:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Log out"
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        switch Section(section: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section) {
        case .Theme:
            self.theme = Theme(row: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        case .ApplePay:
            self.applePay = Switch(row: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        case .RequiredBillingAddressFields:
            self.requiredBillingAddressFields = RequiredBillingAddressFields(row: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        case .RequiredShippingAddressFields:
            self.requiredShippingAddressFields = RequiredShippingAddressFields(row: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        case .ShippingType:
            self.shippingType = ShippingType(row: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        case .Session:
            let cookieStore = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
            for cookie in cookieStore.cookies ?? [] {
                cookieStore.deleteCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section), with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ChefEV' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ChefEV


pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod ‘Firebase/Database’
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'Alamofire'

  target 'ChefEVTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ChefEVUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

any help in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything wrong during `pod install`? Can you post your `Podfile`?

Comment: ive added the pod file to the question! no issues while running pod install @Ryan

Answer (score 1):

solved this problem by updating the stripe podfiles. apparently installing the Stripe pod files does not give you the up-to-date version

type:  `pod update Stripe` into project terminal and should solve this issue.